# Delete Win8 On Spare HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Win10 machine. The OS is on a SSD. Today I put in a empty 250GB SSD for storage and a 1TB HDD that has Win8 on it for storage as well. Since I'm not booting from the HDD and the OS on the SSD finds everything on the HDD with no problem could I delete the Windows files off of the HDD without any issues?

thanks

Comment: If you don't want to boot to Windows 8 you can format the hdd if you want

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is there are other partitions on the hard drive that will use up storage. You will need to also delete those with a partition manager such as "disk management" or "gparted", then extend the root partition to fill up the entire drive. From there, yes, you can delete the windows files and keep the files you want.